# How to use custom execution for testCompile goal for maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I am using an `annotationProcessor` with maven-compiler-plugin in a custom profile.

```xml
<profile>                                                       
  <id>error-prone-test-compile</id>                             
  <build>                                                       
    <plugins>                                                   
      <plugin>                                                  
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>             
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
        <version>3.10.1</version>                               
        <executions>                                            
          <execution>                                           
            <id>test-compile-error-prone</id>                   
            <phase>test-compile</phase>                         
            <goals>                                             
              <goal>testCompile</goal>                          
            </goals>                                            
            <configuration>                                     
              <failOnError>false</failOnError>                  
              <source>${java.version}</source>                  
              <target>${java.version}</target>                  
              <compilerArgs>                                    
                <arg>-Xpkginfo:always</arg>                     
                <arg>-XDcompilePolicy=simple</arg>              
                <arg>                                           
                  -Xplugin:ErrorProne \                         
                  -XepExcludedPaths:.*[\\/]resources[\\/].*     
                </arg>                                          
              </compilerArgs>                                   
              <annotationProcessorPaths>                        
                <path>                                          
                  <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>      
                  <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>     
                  <version>${error-prone.version}</version>     
                </path>                                         
              </annotationProcessorPaths>                       
            </configuration>                                    
          </execution>                                          
        </executions>                                           
      </plugin>                                                 
    </plugins>                                                  
  </build>                                                      
</profile>
```

Not using the current config, when running

```bash
mvn clean test-compile -Perror-prone-test-compile
```

the testCompile goal is executed twice (`default-testCompile` and `test-compile-error-prone`):

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ checkstyle ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2945 source files to /home/vyom/IdeaProjects/checkstyle/target/test-classes
[INFO] /home/vyom/IdeaProjects/checkstyle/src/test/resources/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/regexp/regexp/InputRegexpSemantic12.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] /home/vyom/IdeaProjects/checkstyle/src/test/resources/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/regexp/regexp/InputRegexpSemantic12.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] /home/vyom/IdeaProjects/checkstyle/src/test/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/internal/utils/TestUtil.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /home/vyom/IdeaProjects/checkstyle/src/test/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/internal/utils/TestUtil.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (test-compile-error-prone) @ checkstyle ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
```

I want to replace `default-testCompile` with `test-compile-error-prone` i.e. only execute `test-compile-error-prone` and not execute `default-testCompile`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `skip` `default-testCompile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the `default-testCompile`:

```
  <execution>                                           
    <id>default-testCompile</id>
    <phase>test-compile</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
    </goals>                   

    <configuration>                                     
      <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
  </execution>                  
  <execution>                                           
    <id>test-compile-error-prone</id>                   
    <phase>test-compile</phase>                         
    <goals>                                             
      <goal>testCompile</goal>                          
    </goals>                                            
    <configuration>                                     
      <failOnError>false</failOnError>
```